# cpp:585:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: ros, industrial-robot

I am using this [Repo](https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Kinematics-Project.git)

when building the projects I am getting this error

Ros - noetic

```
[ 83%] Building CXX object RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp.o
/home/guru/my_bots/Udacity_robot/src/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/src/trajectory_sampler.cpp: In member function ‘bool TrajectorySampler::SetupCollisionObject(const string&, const string&, const Pose&, moveit_msgs::CollisionObject&)’:

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2670: RoboND-Kinematics-Project/kuka_arm/CMakeFiles/trajectory_sampler.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeFiles/gazebo_grasp_fix.dir/build.make:76: RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeFiles/gazebo_grasp_fix.dir/src/GazeboGraspGripper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeFiles/gazebo_grasp_fix.dir/build.make:63: RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeFiles/gazebo_grasp_fix.dir/src/GazeboGraspFix.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:706: RoboND-Kinematics-Project/gazebo_grasp_plugin/CMakeFiles/gazebo_grasp_fix.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The project appears to have an upstream ticket about the issue.

The warning you cite is a warning not the error that's stopping compile.

At least one of the errors in this is already ticketed on the repository.

https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Kinematics-Project/issues/24

I would suggest that you follow up over there.

To get better help here. Please ask a question with a self contained minimal example which can be reproduced by whoever is trying to help you.

Comment: its not solved there yet

Comment: As there's one or more bugs in the upstream code that's the place to follow up on it. If you want help with understanding the general compiler warnings and errors that's [off topic for this forum](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ) but the main stack overflow can help you with understanding the programming error. If you want significant help with that you will have the best luck isolating it down to a [short self contained correct example](http://sscce.org/).